# What have I done wrong in the Android code?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I've followed a tutorial for a basic local login screen and despite following the tutorial exactly, I've hit some errors. I don't know exactly what they mean or how to solve them, could anybody help out?

http://imageshack.us/f/856/codeo.jpg/ - This is a screenshot of my current code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your `btn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener)` requires `View.OnClickListener` object but you're passing it `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` object. Hence why your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

You have confused the [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) with the [DialogInterface.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener.html) . You have also confused pasting text with posting blurry low res images of code in the cloud :-D

Answer (score 1):

Use `new View.OnClickListener`. It is different the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` which you probably imported.